# iPhone 5 + IOS 7 UIPageViewController issue

Tags: ios, iphone, uipageviewcontroller

I am using the UIPageViewController to display the linked data, on swipe. It is working for all devices, but the issues is on iPhone 5/5s if I swipe from the edge (black portion of the screen) of the phone it is pop the main view controller, instead of displaying the next child view controller.

How can handle this condition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is controlled by the `interactivePopGestureRecognizer` of the navigation controller. You can disable it using:

```
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
```